# Fix and shrink Incorrect history

Tags: sql, teradata

I Have to write SQL for shrink incorrect history data as below :

```
      K1   K2   D1  D2  start_date  End_date
       1    2   A   B   04-08-2018  05-08-2018
       1    2   A   B   05-08-2018  06-08-2018
       1    2   A   B   06-08-2018  08-08-2018
       3    4   P   Q   04-08-2018  05-08-2018
       3    4   P   Q   05-08-2018  06-08-2018
       3    4   P   Q   06-08-2018  31-12-2018
       1    2   C   D   04-08-2018  05-08-2018
       1    2   C   D   05-08-2018  06-08-2018
       1    2   C   D   06-08-2018  31-12-2018
       1    2   A   B   08-08-2018  09-08-2018
       1    2   A   B   09-08-2018  10-08-2018
       1    2   A   B   10-08-2018  31-12-2018
```

where K1 and K2 are my Key columns.
For some reason I have duplicate history data and need to fix that but have to maintain the occurrence of records.
Here I have to merge continuous history into one and output is as below

```
      K1    K2  D1  D2  start_date  end_date
       1    2   A   B   04-08-2018  08-08-2018
       3    4   P   Q   04-08-2018  31-12-2018
       1    2   C   D   04-08-2018  31-12-2018
       1    2   A   B   08-08-2018  31-12-2018
```

( Please ignore the future dates , its just for sampling).

Comment: Why down vote at least share it in comments. Don't misuse your rights

Comment: I didn't downvote. There is no such thing as continuous rows in SQL. There isn't any way to keep the two sets of (1, 2, A, B) distinct unless there is other data available for sorting. If there is another column then you need to look up "gaps and islands" and "group by".

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why do you keep two distinct rows 1,2,A,B in the result ???  You need to learn that database tables ***DO NOT HAVE ANY ROW ORDERING***.  And that as a consequence there is no such thing as a row that "appears in between two others".  The only thing that matters about the rows is what is ***inside***.  Unless and until you learn that, you're bound to keep using SQL technology the wrong way.

Comment: @ErwinSmout I know SQL does not have anything like row ordering, I was only referring to gaps in data load wrt start_date and not its ordering. Anyways we have created the SQL and fixed the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think the end dates can be ignored, so this is a simple gaps and islands problem:

```
select k1, k2, d1, d2,
       min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by k1, k2 order by start_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by k1, k2, d1, d2 order by start_date) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by k1, k2, d1, d2, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Comment: Does this really do what's requested ?  (Just asking because to me it looks suspect.)

Comment: sorry mislooked consider unasked

Comment: But does it retain both of 1,2,A,B,dt1,dt2 and 1,2,A,B,dt8,dt9 if those are all the rows there are ?   The generated row_numbers seem (1,1) and (2,2) to me so the (fifth) grouping value is 0 in both cases so they get grouped together yielding one single row dt1,dt9.

Comment: @ErwinSmout . . . No, but that does not appear to be how the OP's data is structured.

Comment: In that case it is very much worth mentioning ALL the assumptions underlying the gaps-and-islands aproach because if the OP hasn't confirmed explicitly any of those it actually isn't up to you to start making them ...

Answer (score 1):

Below Will solve your issue:

```
SELECT K1,K2,D1,D2,
       -- THIS SPLITS THE PERIOD BACK TO SEPERATE COLUMNS 
       BEGIN(PD) AS START_DT, NULLIF(END(PD), DATE '9999-12-31') AS END_DT
    FROM
    ( 
       SELECT NORMALIZE -- THIS RETURNS YOUR NORMALIZED RESULT AS A PERIOD
          K1,K2,D1,D2,
          PERIOD(START_DT,COALESCE(END_DT, DATE '9999-12-31')) AS PD
       FROM TEST2  WHERE START_DT < END_DT
    ) AS DT
```